# Spring boot controller fails to hit error 404

Tags: java, spring-boot, multi-module

I am building this Spring Boot application with Hibernate and MySQL. I know this is pretty basic and the same question is asked multiple times but I can't figure out why my controller isn't hitting and gives 404 error. As I see, the problem is with `ComponentScan` where my `@SpringBootApplication` and `@RestController` reside within one package while my `@Repository` and `@Entity` lie in another package.
When I include the package as `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.sample.user")`, the project builds and runs successfully but does not hit the GET method `getUser()` and no console output of an error as well. The GET method hits only when I omit the 
`@Autowired private UserRepository userRepository;` from the controller class along with `@ComponentScan` in application class.

**Controller**

```
package com.sample.rest.controller;

import com.sample.user.entity.User;
import com.sample.user.repository.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping ("user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public User getUser() {
        User user  = new User();
        user.setFirstName("Lady");
        user.setLastName("Gaga");
        user.setEmail("l.gaga@ymail.com");
        userRepository.save(user);
        return user;
    }
}
```

**Application**

```
package com.sample.rest;

import com.sample.rest.controller.UserController;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.sample.user")
public class RestServicesApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestServicesApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**Repository Interface**

```
package com.sample.user.repository;

import com.sample.user.entity.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@EnableJpaRepositories
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {}
```

**Entity**

```
package com.sample.user.entity;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "email_address", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
}
```

**Browser Page**
https://ibb.co/KDsqLn3

Answer (score 2):

With `@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.sample.user")` you are overwriting the default behavior.

So either remove this and put the packages below the package where you have `@SpringBootApplication` or add all packages to `@ComponentScan`.

I recommend not to use the default Spring Boot behavior.

So remove `ComponentScan` an move `RestServicesApplication` to the `com.sample` package

Comment: `@SpringBootApplication` is in `com.sample.rest` package and `@Repository` is in `com.sample.user` package so I don't understand your point, _putting below the package where I have_ ` @SpringBootApplication`. There's nothing below it because they are in different packages. Appreciate any clarification :)

Comment: According to @SimonMartinelli he is saying that bring all package inside the com.sample.rest then spring boot automatically detect all package inside com.sample.rest. you don'yt required then component scan annotation. or use @ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.sample") so that boot will detect all package after com.sample

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Thanks for the update and that makes sense. But can't we resolve the issue in the way it is currently? Your solution seems a complete redo

Comment: It's not a complete redo. It's just moving one class in another package. But have a look at the solution of @Kandy too

Answer (score 0):

Use this it will resolve your Issue.

`@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.sample")`

or use multiple package sacn somthing like

`@ComponentScan({ "com.sample", "com.sample.user" })`